# Asynchronous API calls in loop python

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I am trying to store a list of objects using `Tweepy`'s `statuses_lookup` api call. Each call to `statuses_lookup` takes in a list of IDs, and can contain up to 100 IDs.

This function below takes in a list of IDs, and I am trying to append all the metadata returned from the API call into the `tweetData` list.

```
def lookupTweets(self, tweetIds):
    tweetData = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(tweetIds):
        print(i)
        if len(tweetIds) - i > 0:
            statuses = self.status_lookup(tweetIds[i + 99])
        else:
            statuses = self.status_lookup(tweetIds[i, len(tweetIds) - i])

        tweetData.append(statuses)
        i += 100

    return tweetData
```

And here is the async function that makes the api call

```
async def status_lookup(self, tweets):
        return self.api.statuses_lookup(tweets)
```

And here is the main method:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    twitterEngine = TwitterEngine()
    tweets = twitterEngine.ingestData("democratic-candidate-timelines.txt")

    twitterData = twitterEngine.lookupTweets(tweets)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(twitterData))
    print(twitterData)
```

When I print the result of `twitterData`, I get a list of `coroutine objects`. The output looks something like this: `[<coroutine object TwitterEngine.status_lookup at 0x105bd16d0>]`. However, I want the actual metadata and not the coroutine object.

I'm new to async programming in Python, and any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does tweepy library support async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coroutine objects, the result of calling `async def` functions, need to be associated with futures to get access to the returned value.

There are several ways of doing this, but if you have a list of coroutine objects, you can use `asyncio.gather`:

```
twitterData = twitterEngine.lookupTweets(tweets)
future = asyncio.gather(*twitterData)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(future)
print(future.result())
```

Comment: This looks promising, but the result from printing `future.result()` is list of empty lists: `[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]`

Comment: @VarunVu If you add `print(tweetData)` just before the `return` in `lookupTweets`, does it show non-empty lists?

Comment: It shows a list of `coroutine objects`, like so: `[<coroutine object TwitterEngine.status_lookup at 0x105bda360>, <coroutine object TwitterEngine.status_lookup at 0x105bdaa98>...]`

Comment: @VarunVu Ah ok... and just to confirm, `self.api.statuses_lookup(tweets)` does return something that isn't empty?

Comment: Ah I made a dumb mistake with my slicing, I put a comma instead of a semicolon! Thanks!!

Comment: It seems the real problem with the OP's code is that it's not really async in the first place (apparently the underlying library is not async). So `status_lookup` can be an ordinary `def` and the event loop is not even needed.

Answer (score 3):

> When I print the result of `twitterData`, I get a list of `coroutine object`s.

Calling a coroutine function will just create the coroutine object, much like invoking a generator just creates the generator object. To get actual data from a coroutine object, you need to either *await* it from another coroutine, or run it in the event loop. In case of `status_lookup`, `lookupTweets` should itself be an `async def` coroutine, and it should `await` the statuses:

```
statuses = await self.status_lookup(tweetIds[i + 99])
```

The same goes for `status_lookup`:

```
async def status_lookup(self, tweets):
    return await self.api.statuses_lookup(tweets)
```

The return value of the outer-most coroutine will be returned by `run_until_complete`:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
twitterData = loop.run_until_complete(twitterEngine.lookupTweets(tweets))    
print(twitterData)
```

Comment: When I set `status_lookup` to be async, I get the following error: `TypeError: object ResultSet can't be used in 'await' expression`

Comment: @VarunVu It seems that `status_lookup` is not a coroutine. Is tweepy asyncio aware at all?